# Cascaded current control

Tags: current, motor, control, control-loop

I have a actuator capable of measuring motor current and position via an encoder on the output shaft. The motor is a brushed DC motor  running through a gearbox.

My questions is in regards to the use of a cascaded controller model where by the output of the velocity controller sets the setpoint of the current controller. What I do not understand about this is when velocity tracking and a disturbance torque is encountered the current controller aims to reduce the output voltage to maintain the current and the velocity controller aims to increase the output voltage (via the current controller) to maintain speed. Due the response of the system this causes an exaggerated tracking error when compared to direct velocity control (Voltage Control). A feedforward term does slightly increase tracking performance but not significantly.

[image]

Is there something I am missing here? It would make more sense for the current controller to increase the current setpoint when the current measurement is increased. The reason for requiring a current control loop is to be able to set variable max current limits. Switching between "voltage control" & "Current Control" at the limits does not have a smooth response.

A example of this is shown in the image below. The first half of the graph shows the current controller being switch off and the second half shows it being turned on. The Oscillations are from a disturbance torque. It is clear that the tracking error is increased due to the current controller trying to maintain constant torque.

[image]

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is actually doing your processing in this case?

Comment: A microcontroller

Comment: Ok.  Wasn't sure if it was actually 2 microcontrollers.

Comment: Gave you a starter answer, I'm just reading your post some more to evaluate what it should be trying to do.

Comment: What are the nature of your disturbance torques? RC car driving over rocks or gusts of wind hitting a fan for instance and how do you wish the motor to perform when it receives countertorque?

Comment: Most typically the disturbance torque comes from runout in the gearing where by the friction is increased at certain points and therefore a higher voltage is required to maintain the same speed.

Comment: So is it fair to say it's ideal for the motor to maintain it's speed absolutely up to, say 90% of it's current limit, at which point a shutdown is necessary as something is jamming the gears?

Comment: It is ideal for the motor to maintain its speed absolutely until it reaches its current limit at which point it should maintain that current but no more. If one simply switches modes to "current control" at the current limit it is difficult to maintain a smooth response.

Comment: What caused the incident at the center of the graph?  Is that just intentional stop and start or is it a blocked rotor incident?

Comment: That is just because the way I am switching the current controller on and off is by setting the PI gains from just a feed forward value. It can be ignored

Comment: Ok.  And the first part of the graph, where velocity is behaving nicely, is that running at a lower speed?

Comment: In the first half of the graph the current loop is bypassed and the velocity loop simply controls the voltage (duty cycle) of the motor. The second half makes use of the current controller. Obviously tuning can give better results but comparatively the second half is always produces a larger tracking error.

Comment: Does the current control function by limiting available current or is it able to boost voltage/current as well?

Comment: I think if you change it so that full voltage is always available and speed and current feedback both simply control duty cycle it should solve your problem.  Or if you're not using PWM, just have them control a shared value of voltage capable of spanning the full range.

Answer (score 2):

You should split the loop in two. Lock the rotor and then tune the inner PI controller (current controller). You should get a neat response. Then connect both controllers and then tune the speed controller.

The inner is a slave controller, it takes the setpoint value from outer controller. Usually the inner has to be faster, usually the current loop is executed with higher frequency than velocity loop, but it does not matter.

This is a speed controller:
[image: Speed controller]

You can notice the lowpass filter on the begining. It's purpose is to delay the action in order to wait that current loop corrects the error before the speed loop takes an action. Makes sense that it takes time for the controller to correct the error, so you have to wait for a while in the outer loop. Notice also the units:

- speed: radians
- dynamic torque (M_dinam): Nm - ommit it for now
- friction torque (M_frikcije): Nm - forget about it
- dead weight (M_teze) - forget it
- speed controller: Kp - Nms/rad
- the output is torque setpoint Nm

Let's go further to the pre-current loop:

[image]

It's a set of limitators, power, torque, current. But then a very important thing, a current constant. The torque setpoint becomes a current setpoint by multiplying ki. The other boxes are notch filters and low pass filter to elimenate the system self-resonance, but skip this.

Finnaly, the current loop:

[image]

Note the units of Kp: V/A. It means that output is voltage setpoint, that can be translated to PWM duty cycle.

What you should change in your model:

Add a low pass filter on speed loop. You have seen that you can't switch on/off the current loop unless you multiply the output of the speed loop with some constant. Which turns that your approach to simply turn off/on changes also the total loop gain and you should have two parameter sets.

Comment: From what I can make out this is exactly what I have got. My example graph is not a direct comparison but the difference in velocity error is still apparent no matter on tuning.   The issue is still the delay caused when tracking a velocity as the current controller does not "correct the error" in velocity it actually decreases the velocity making it worse. Current controller is tuned independently and runs 4x faster than velocity.

Comment: The cascaded loop makes the whole system more dynamic a faster response. The current controller regulates the current, without it the sytem response time should be larger. IMO the whole loop isn't properly tuned. Or the implementation of the PI isn't good,...I can't say more, since I don't know how you did it. There is no flaw in the concept, all industrial drives works like that, something in your work doesn't work well. Try to increase gain of the velocity controller, show some tunning results, I can't help without your further work and tries.

Comment: "It's purpose is to delay the action in order to wait that current loop corrects the error before the speed loop takes an action" The action taken by the current loop to correct the error reduces the velocity and therefore before the velocity loop corrects it we have already experienced a velocity tracking error. Very much appreciate your help and I will try and get some examples to post today.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič could you please answer the question at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/669916/196712

Answer (score 0):

By putting a current loop in, effectively you've built yourself a constant torque, variable speed motor, so the nature of the device is to allow speed to change in order to keep torque the same.

The second loop attempts to use this constant torque variable speed arrangement to control speed, so if just the second loop was controlling the motor, it would be a (variable) constant speed variable torque motor.

I believe the complications in your control mechanism stem from using these two directly conflicting control arrangements.  I would suggest that attempting to combine the control mechanisms in the correct way will solve the problem.  Keeping them in their opposing separate forms and trying to counter their nature would be much more difficult.

Comment: Thanks for this response. This is what I suspect but just find it interesting that it is such a common topology. It does provide a very elegant way of setting current/torque limits which is desirable in this application.

Comment: @PaulPhillips Nothing is conflicting in your arrangement, you're on the right way. Peehaps the controllers are not correctly tuned or they are not correctly writen/executed. The major issue could be the implementation of integrator anti-windup an then recovery from saturation. You can post the PI implemetation and show outputs in % of both controllers. Your trend is not very clear. The current measurement has also some weird measurement spikes of values 0.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Would you be able to explain then why it makes sense that current aims to decrease voltage where velocity aims to increase it when encountering a disturbance?

Comment: @PaulPhillips It's the nature of the setup. At the obsatcle the current rises and the current controller tends to lower the voltage, but the speed loop tends to increse the current. The speed loop will be the winner, because it is higher priority. Again: your comparison between off/on current control is not good. Because you probably bypassed the current controller, in this case yo should also multiply the ouptut value with the same Kp of current controller, to compare.

Comment: I tend to agree with K H here from an experimental standpoint.

Comment: I think he's probably right too.  Many of these "standard arrangement"s you can find work well when used in the correct way.  I have my suspicions about how I would expect this feedback loop to work. You may need to add a more in depth explanation of the control mechanism.